# $X$ local compact metric space contains countable dense subset $\Rightarrow X=\cup_{j=1}^{\infty} K_j$, $K_1\subset K_2\subset…$ compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be locally compact metric space, that is every point is surrounded by a compact neighbourhood. Show that

> If $X$ contains a countable dense subset $T$, then there are compact subsets $K_1\subset K_2\subset…$ so that $X=\cup_{j=1}^{\infty} K_j$

Let $t_i$ be elements of $T$, since $X$ is locally compact there is $\epsilon>0$ so that $\overline{B_{\epsilon}(t_i)}$ is compact and $X=\cup \{\overline{B_{\epsilon}(t_i)}|\epsilon\in \mathbb{Q}\}$. But how can I create an increasing sequences of compact sets?

Comment: Do you only consider metric spces?

Comment: @PaulFrost he must be otherwise it is false.

Comment: @PaulFrost The rational sequence topology (or Mrówka $\Psi$) are Tychonoff separable locally compact and not $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: There need not be one $\varepsilon$ that works for all $t_i$ at the same time..And if we have a different $r_i$ per $t_i$ the claim that the union is $X$ is possibly false.

Answer (score 1):

If we're in a metric space, a countable dense set means there is a countable base.

This means there is also a countable base $\{B_n\}$ so that $\overline{B_n}$ are all compact (follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/65441/4280)).

Then apply the fact that finite unions of compact sets are compact to easily modify this to an increasing sequence of compacta.

Comment: I take $K_j=\cup{n=0}^j \overline{ B_n}$, why is then $X=\cup_{j=0}^{\infty} K_j$?

Comment: @user30523 if $K_j = \bigcup_{i=0}^j \overline{B_i}$ then the union of the $K_j$ the same as those all those closures hence equal to $X$.

Comment: $\{B_n\}$ countable base of $X$ means that $X=\cup_n B_n$?

Comment: @user30523 so certainly the closures too.

Comment: why can I find a base so that the closures are compact?

Comment: @user30523 that’s a standard fact.